# I'm trying to 'shuffle' a folder of music and there is an error where random.choice() keeps choosing things that it is supposed to have removed

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

I'm trying to make a python script that renames files randomly from a list and I used numbers.remove(place) on it but it keeps choosing values that are supposed to have been removed.

I used to just use random.randint but now I have moved to choosing from a list then removing the chosen value from the list but it seems to keep choosing chosen values.

'''python

```
from os import chdir, listdir, rename
from random import choice


def main():
    chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Folders\\Music')
    for f in listdir():
        if f.endswith('.mp4'):
            numbers = [str(x) for x in range(0, 100)]
            had = []
            print(f'numbers = {numbers}')
            place = choice(numbers)
            print(f'place = {place}')
            numbers.remove(place)
            print(f'numbers = {numbers}')
            while place in had:
                input('Place has been had.')
                place = choice(numbers)
            had.append(place)
            name = place + '.mp4'
            print(f'name = {name}')
            print(f'\n\nRenaming {f} to {name}.\n\n')
            try:
                rename(f, name)
            except FileExistsError:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'''

It should randomly number the files without choosing the same value for a file twice but it does that and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `listdir()` the first time, that's the same list that you're iterating over the entire time. Yes, you're changing the contents of the directory, but python doesn't really care about that because you only asked for the contents of the directory *at a specific point in time* - before you began modifying it.

I would do this in two separate steps:

```
# get the current list of files in the directory
dirlist = os.listdir()
# choose a new name for each file
to_rename = zip(
    dirlist, 
    [f'{num}.mp4' for num in random.sample(range(100), len(dirlist))]
)
# actually rename each file
for oldname, newname in to_rename:
    try:
        os.rename(oldname, newname)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

This method is more concise than the one you're using. First, I use `random.sample()` on the iterable `range(100)` to generate non-overlapping numbers from that range (without having to do the extra step of using `had` like you're doing now). I generate exactly as many as I need, and then use the built-in `zip()` function to bind together the original filenames with these new numbers.

Then, I do the `rename()` operations all at once.

Comment: Thanks so much man, I get told all the time to stop just adding more but i need to get more experience and confidence with the modules and then hopefully I will know about this stuff and not need to ask about it. I did make a slight edit to make sure the original file ended with .mp4 but other than that this fully works. Thank you.